# typescript: visual studio code can't get the correct typings for mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#quick-example) quick example to work with sql server db from node.

I already ran

```
npm install mssql -s
npm install @types/mssql -s
```

and I try with this example

```
import sql from 'mssql';

(async () => {
  try {
    await sql.connect('mssql://xxxxuser:xxxpass!@localhost/xxxdb');
    const result = await sql.query`select * from xxxtable`;
    console.dir(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

the example works fine, but visual studio code gives me the following warning on `sql.connect` and `sql.query`:

```
[ts] Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'typeof import("xxx/db_crawler/node_modules/@types/mssql/index")'. [2339]
----
any
```

Any idea how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: `--esModuleInterop` or `import sql = require("mssql");`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using msnodesqlv8?
that fixed my problems !

Implementing :
npm install mssql
npm install msnodesqlv8

const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");

```js
 const connection = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    server: ServerName,
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    options: {
      trustedConnection: true
    }
  });
  connection.connect().then(() => {
    connection.query(
      `select * from xxxtable`,
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else { 
  console.log(result);
        }
      }
    );
  });
```